# Sql statement to get single cell value

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to get a single cell value from the table. And I am using hibernate with Spring MVC.

I did is:

```
Session s = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();  
query q= s.createQuery("select xxx from abc where asd=:asd");
```

now, I need to save this single value into a string variable and need to use this string variable to compare with other string in a jsp page using `<c:choose> <c:when> <c:otherwise>` tags...

This is what I have now..

```
@Transactional
public String getUseNis(String code) {
Session s = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Query q = s.createQuery("select useNis from tle_location where code = :code");
q.setString("code", code);
String result = (String) q.uniqueResult();
return result;
```

I need to use the return value in a jsp page to check for either yes or no...how to pass it to my jsp page..

Comment: That is relatively typical task. How does implementation look at the moment and which kind of problems (if any) you have with it?

Comment: No issues till now..! All the other implementations works fine..I am stuck with this requirement...even jsp page c tags works fine(checked with different set of values)..only thing is how to save that particular sql statement value into a string variable..if it works I can get it work with other part..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a single result, use either `getFirstResult()` or `getSingleResult()`. **Note** that neither is particularly useful in your case for these reasons:

- Invoking `getFirstResult()` will return the first element in the
  collection returned by your query which may or may not be the
  element you are looking for.
- Invoking `getUniqueResult()` expects the query to return
  *exactly* one item, and causes an exception to be thrown, if the collection returned is empty or has more than one entry.

An illustration with [`uniqueResult()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29).

```java
//sessionFactory = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory();
Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("select value from table where ...");
query.setParameters("param1", value1);
result = (Type) query.uniqueResult(); //The type is you desired result type.
//test for null here if needed
```

Make sure that the query returns only a **single** result. It will throw `NonUniqueResultException` - if there more than one matching result is found (Therefore `query.setMaxResults(1);` would be more appropriate).

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/UniqueResultHQL.htm

Answer (score 0):

First you have have to set value for :asd, but that is probably clear.

Then you go and execute query and convert result. Because you seem to expect that this query returns single value, it can be executed via [Query.uniqueResult](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29). If you want to take some specific action in case when assumption about one and only one non-null result was wrong, please react to returned null value or thrown [NonUniqueResultException](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/NonUniqueResultException.html) accordingly.

How the result of query is converted to string depends of course about type of `xxx` and preferred format of String presentation. Some examples follows:

```
//type of xxx is already string
String result = (String) q.uniqueResult();

//type of xxx is Integer
Integer res = (Integer) q.uniqueResult();
String result = res.toString();
```

Comment: This is what I have now..

    `@Transactional
    public String getUseNis(String code) {
    Session s = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Query q = s.createQuery("select useNis from tle_location where code = :code");
    q.setString("code", code);
    String result = (String) q.uniqueResult();
    return result; `

I need to use the return value in a jsp page to check for either yes or no...how to pass it to my jsp page..

Comment: I understood that your original question was how to get single String out of query because of following comment: "only thing is how to save that particular sql statement value into a string variable..if it works I can get it work with other part."

Comment: Yes..still I have issues with that string variable value..Because I am not calling the method anywhere...and I am confused how to call it

Comment: That's then different thing. I only presented answer to original problem. About how to pass values, please take a look to your web framework documentation or store value to you backing bean or directly to session.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller write below code

```
// Fetch the result by executing query and store it into string variable as
String typeofpayment = serviceObj.getValueFromDB();
model.addAttribute("typeofpayment",typeofpayment); // This will pass attribute to jsp page
```

Now in jsp you can use

```
<c:set var="typeOfPaymentVar" value="${typeofpayment}" scope="request" />
<c:choose>
     <c:when test='${typeOfPaymentVar=="cash"}'>
          CASH
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
          OTHER MODE OF PAYMENT
     </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```